# expect(object).toEqual(object) is throwing error Object reading has no method call

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have been trying to compare two javascript objects in jasmine . But I am getting error Object reading has no method call.

```
describe("AutoEditor", function() {

  var widgetList = ["widget1","widget2"];
  var oldEdgeStructure = {};
  oldEdgeStructure.SingleLink = [{"widget1":[{"EdgePosition":"s","WidgetID":"widget2"}]},
    {"widget2":[{"EdgePosition":"n","WidgetID":"widget1"}]}];

  it("read edges", function(done) {

    require(['auto-editor'], function(EdgeStructures) {
        var containerEl = $('#container');
        var edgeStructures = EdgeStructures.readEdges(widgetList,containerEl);
        expect(edgeStructures.SingleLink).toEqual(oldEdgeStructure.SingleLink);
        done();
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with the expect line, but more probably with the `EdgeStructures.readEdges(widgetList,containerEl);` : it is the only function call in your code that might have call `call`

Answer (score 0):

Was getting the error because I was not loading Edgestructures in body after the divs are appended to the DOM. Michal you are right. I just added the script tag where I was loading my library in the body tag after the DOM content were loaded and the problem got resolved.